# How to change the compiler settings with AutoMake?

Tags: make, automake

I want to build a library with a specific tool instead of GCC.
The regular build sequence is:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Where should I replace the GCC settings (I think that the configure was created with AutoMake)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is usually worth reading output of `./configure --help`. This suggest to run configure as

```
./configure CFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0"
make
make install
```

Overriding `CFLAGS` (or `LDFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, depending on your needs) as follows works as well:

```
CFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0" ./configure
make
make install
```

If you need to use a compiler other than gcc, you have to override the `CC` variable.